# Fluid font-size not working. Conflict with css reset "font: inherit;". Why?

Tags: css, fluid, typography

I want to use a fluid font-size with code from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/ . But my CSS Meyer Reset (font: inherit;) seems to override the code. I don't know why? Here is the code:

The CSS Reset css:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;

}
```

Later code in the css stylesheet to get a fluid font-size between 16px and 40px;

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  :root {
    font-size: calc(16px + (40 - 16) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1000 - 320)));
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  :root {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

Then when I inspect in the browser at say 700px browser size the latter css fluid code is overwritten by the "font: inherit;" in the CSS Reset code. Therefore it does not seem to work with the fluid code. Any ideas? Is it working or not?

[Picture. Inspection tool in browser shows that the latter code is not active?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tan3P.png)

The  fluid font code works but it confuses me that the inspector tool shows that it does not get applied and only shows that the reset css font:inherit gets applied. Why?

Comment: but it's inherit, so it will work by inherting the value your are defining: https://jsfiddle.net/2m7vtj9x/ (resize and see)

Comment: So you mean my code actually works, even though the css reset font property overrides the fluid media query code?

Comment: test it by yourself and see. I guess you know how it should behave so you can see if it's working or not

Comment: It seems to work but it confuses me that the inspection tool cancels the media query code. For me that says it does not get applied? See picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MDN: inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)

> The inherit CSS keyword causes the element for which it is specified to take the **computed value** of the property from its parent element.

So if the css rule of the media query is applied to `:root` and its descendants all have `font: inhert` they will inherit the font settings from `:root`

If all element (like `p`) wouldn't have `font-size` set to `inherit` but instead would have the computed value, then you could not change the font size of a certain element and let those settings propagate to its descendants, but you would need to set it on each of the descendants too. So having the `font-…` properties set to `inherit` is the intended behavior.

Here the `font-size` is applied to each element directly, if you change the font size of `p` it does not apply for `span`:

```css
* {
  font-size: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd <span>gubergren</span>, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> 
</div>
```

On the other hand, if `font-size` is `inherit`, so if you set the `font-size` it will propagate to the children.

```css
* {
  font-size: inherit;
}

div {
  font-size: 20px;
}


p {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd <span>gubergren</span>, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: But when I inspect your code it does override the inherit value.  See the picture https://imgur.com/a/V86tJMQ . In my code the latter css code does not override the inherit value (see the picture in my post).

Comment: @TobiasAndersson look at the `<span>gubergren</span>` element, in both snippets. In the first one the size is applied to all elements, so changing `p` does not effect `span`(which is not what you normally want), in the second example all elements have `inherit` except the one for which the size is set, so `span` inherits the size of `p`.

Comment: I understand this. And therefore I expect the inspector tool to apply my media query code and not override it (see the picture in my first post). The inspector tool shows the font-size is inherited and applies that rule instead (and crosses over the media query code which is the code I want to be used).

Comment: The  fluid font code works but it confuses me that the inspector tool shows that it does not get applied and only shows that the reset css font:inherit gets applied.

Comment: @TobiasAndersson because your media query `font-size` is applied to `:root` and not your `p` element, the font size is as of that calculated for the `:root` element. And for your `p`: it element **inherits** the **compute** value of its parent, so the rule of `:root` for `font-size` propagates through the descendant as long as none of the descendants has set it explicitly to a different rule. Look at the inspector a `Computed` and not at `Style` if you want the computed information. `Styles` are the rules of how the value should be computed, not the final value.

Comment: This clarified it for me. Thanks!